# Connect BD with API REST in heroku

Tags: rest, heroku, swagger, slim

I need connect an API REST with a database in `Heroku`. My `API REST` have designed with `slim` and `swagger`. I have created the following Config Vars in `Heroku`:

- `DATABASE_CHARSET`
- `DATABASE_DRIVER`
- `DATABASE_HOST`
- `DATABASE_NAME`
- `DATABASE_PASSWD`
- `DATABASE_PORT`
- `DATABASE_USER`

However, when I make any request to the server I get the following `Slim` error:

[image]

In this [url](https://matchport.herokuapp.com/App.php) you can see my app. Therefore, I get `404 Error` (HTTP) in each petition ([swagger](https://matchport.herokuapp.com))

Solutions?

Comment: Check your database server and database settings.

Comment: Where? My problem is that I don't know where I can create a database in `heroku` free

Comment: I don't know. May this helps: https://selimsalihovic.github.io/2016-02-07-using-mysql-on-heroku/